# Using an array to decode numbers to letters

Tags: c

For my task I have to print numbers to the screen and decode them into their specific letters. I'm using only the letters a-l in this code just to keep it simple so I can understand it.

The problem I'm having is that when I, for example, put in the number 0 which corresponds to the first entry to the array which is a, it will take out a and print b-l.

How do I make it so if I put in the number 0, the code will print only a to the screen?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
char code[] = "abcdefghijkl";
int i, j, k;
printf("how many letters does your code contain?: ");
scanf("%d", &j);
for(i=0; i<j; ++i){
    printf("enter a number between 0 and 11\n");
    scanf("%d", &k);
    printf("%s\n", &code[k]);
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You print only the character at that location, so change

```
printf("%s\n", &code[k]);
```

to

```
printf("%c\n", code[k]);
```

You should also check that the value you read into `k` is >= 0 && < 11 , otherwise you'll access the array outside its bounds.

Comment: i tried that and getting the following error:
code.c:12:3: warning: format ‘%c’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat]

Comment: @user1304516 Then the code you've posted is not the same as the code you're compiling.

Comment: @user1304516: You need to remove `&` also while printing?

Comment: it is, and the error was wrong i tried changing char to int but it had the same error, it's actually 'char *' instead of 'int *'
ohh that was the problem, thank you!

Comment: @user1304516 printf("%c\n", code[k]); copy this as it is, i think you did not remove '&'

Comment: if i wanted to enter a letter and get a number back so just the reverse, how would i do that?

Comment: Do a simple search over the array or create some sort of lookup. E.g. for(i=0;i<length;++i){if(code[i] == letter){printf("%d\n", i);break;}}

Comment: hmm one of the other exercises required a search, but i don't quite understand how to do it :\

Comment: @user1304516 You loop over all the characters in the array, and compare that character with the character entered, if it is equal, the index is the loop counter, and you break out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

`%s` format specifier is used for printing strings, you need to use `%c` specifier which prints a character to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

`printf("%c\n", code[k]);`  instead of `printf("%s\n", &code[k]);`